# Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.io.File. The default value <null> was returned

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to share an **.mp3** file from the cache folder by doing this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(UriUtils.getResourceUri(audioToShare.getAudioPath(),this));
                File fileToShare = FileUtils.writeStreamToFile(this,audioToShare.getLabel(),inputStream);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("audio/mpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(fileToShare));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));
```

But then when I pick a contact, let's say on whatsapp, the app throws bellow's warning.

```
W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.io.File.  The default value <null> was returned.
12-25 16:10:32.802 17021-17021/com.example.soundboard W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                                                       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:894)
                                                                           at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7075)
                                                                           at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:9887)
                                                                           at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:9867)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1608)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
                                                                           at com.quartzodev.cirosoundboard.sound.SoundActivity.onActionItemClicked(SoundActivity.java:170)
```

Method **writeStreamToFile** so that you can see how I create the cached file

```
public static File writeStreamToFile(Context context, String fileName, InputStream input){

        try {
            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                int read;

                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                output.flush();

                return file;
            } finally {
                output.close();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your onActivityResult method code

Comment: I am not even overriding this. I am not starting this activity expecting for result. Just wanted to share this audio.

Comment: Not sure if related but definitely your next problem - you're not allowed to share files directly (since Android 7). Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Comment: @EugenPechanec you are a true lifesaver. Actually, I got a permission warning when trying to share through Gmail. I changed the method **getFilesDir()** by **getExternalCacheDir()** and now I am able to share it. Get a **FileProvider** in place is definitely the way to go. Please, post an answer about it and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had no permission to share files from folders in **getFilesDir()**

Just changed to **getExternalCacheDir()** and now I can share through Whatsapp and Gmail